# Keep an image inside a max_width, max_height delimited box

Tags: css

I want an image to be 'inside' a box delimited by max_width and max_height.

Instead the image goes over/under the text below.

Should work also in IE10 and above.

```css
.image {
    max-height: 9.75rem;
    max-width: 14.625rem;
    margin: 0 0.75rem 0 0;
}

.image img
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.text {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
```

```html
<div class="section">
     <h3 class="title">Image</h3>
     <div class="image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350"/>
     </div>
 </div>
            
<div class="section">
   <h3 class="title">Item</h3>
   <div class="text">Lorem ipsum sic dolores</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hope this help please try  `.image img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}`

Comment: @jaydeeppatel, updated - the same but I used 90%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should inherit the `max-width` and `max-height` value for `img` from it's `div` container. Please review if this is what you are looking for:

```css
.image {
    max-height: 9.75rem;
    max-width: 14.625rem;
    margin: 0 0.75rem 0 0;
}

.image img{
    max-height: inherit;
    max-width: inherit;
}

.text {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
     <h3 class="title">Image</h3>
     <div class="image">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350"/>
     </div>
 </div>

<div class="section">
   <h3 class="title">Item</h3>
   <div class="text">Lorem ipsum sic dolores</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you set `max-width` or `max-height` you need to have a specified `width` or `height` property here.

```css
.image {
  margin: 0 0.75rem 0 0;
}

.image img {
  max-height: 9.75rem;
  max-width: 14.625rem;
}

.text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="title">Image</h3>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <h3 class="title">Item</h3>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum sic dolores</div>
</div>
```

Comment: object-fit:cover; object-position:center; - not good support for IE

Comment: If you don't wish to use `object-fit` or `object-position` try the code above

Comment: @JMo I edited my answer according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image {
  max-height: 9.75rem;
  max-width: 14.625rem;
  margin: 0 0.75rem 0 0;
}
.image img {
  display:block;
  max-height: 9.75rem;
}
.text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="title">Image</h3>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h3 class="title">Item</h3>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum sic dolores</div>
</div>
```